# How to reduce kurtosis of data

Tags: distributions, python, data-transformation, kurtosis, transform

I'm trying to reduce the kurtosis of my dataset and make it approximately Gaussian, with a common-sense uni-modal shape. The raw data looks like this:

[image]

I first tried `(1+np.log(X.abs())) * np.sign(X)`, but it becomes bimodal which is not what I want, I want approximately Gaussian.

[image]

I then tried `(pow(X.abs() + 1, 0.6) - 1) * np.sign(X)`. It's much better but it's still bimodal.

[image]

How do I properly transform the data, in a way that's computationally fast in a latency sensitive real time application, to make it roughly uni-modal Gaussian but with lower kurtosis?

I considered using `arctan` but that seems a little slow for my application. Ideally I could use `pow` in such a way where I don't get the bimodal outcome.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  The approach, and whether you should even have an approach, depends upon the end use to which you intend to put the distribution.

Comment: @jbowman I'm going to include it in a linear model, but the kurtosis is too large and it's creating spurious outlier spikes in the estimated response. I do have a quantile cap which is a start but I want to just reduce the kurtosis of the entire data through a monotone transform. But the bi-modality I'm getting isn't what I want. I want something with a nice Gaussian shape.

Comment: This is an interesting review paper that may give you some ideas: https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpsyg.2018.02104/full - the title begins with "How to Address Non-normality" and it's in Frontiers of Psychology, in case the link breaks someday.

Answer (score 3):

If your only goal is to make a transformation of your data to normal data, you can simply use the inverse formula.

If you denote by $X$ a random variable with cdf $F$, then $F(X)\sim U$ where $U$ is a uniform distribution. If you denote by $G$ the cdf of a standard normal distribution, you can then obtain normal data via 
$$ G^{-1}(F(X))= G^{-1}(U) \sim N(0,1) $$
Therefore, on your data, you just need to apply the empirical cdf of your data and then the inverse gaussian and you will obtain normal data.